# Prove or disprove: $f(n)\ge \max(f(n),g(n))$ or $g(n)\ge \max(f(n),g(n))$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, asymptotics

Prove or disprove:

> Let $f,g:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ be increasing functions.
>
> $f(n)\ge \max(f(n),g(n))$ or $g(n)\ge \max(f(n),g(n))$ when $n\to \infty$.

I think it's wrong but I'm don't feel very firm in asymptotic calculations>

I guess an example would be $f(n)=n, g(n)=n^2$ then $f(n)\ge \max(f(n),g(n))$ doesn't hold as $f(n)<g(n)$ because
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}n=\infty
$$

Comment: There's an OR in the question not an AND.

Comment: For any *fixed* $n$, we necessarily have that $f(n)=\max\bigl(f(n),g(n)\bigr)$ or $g(n)=\max\bigl(f(n),g(n)\bigr).$ Neither need hold for all $n,$ though.

Comment: Okay. I think I get it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you in fact want to know the following: Given increasing functions $f$ and $g$, is there a $N$ such that for all $n \ge N$ we have $f(n)\ge g(n)$ or other way around?
This is not true: $f(n)=2n+(-1)^n,g(n)=2n+(-1)^{(n+1)}$ is an counter example, if you start with $n \ge 3$, both functions are increasing and for odd $n$, $f(n)<g(n)$ while for even $n$ $g(n)<f(n)$.

Comment: So in both cases either $\max(f(n),g(n)) = f(n)$ OR $\max(f(n), g(n)) = g(n)$

Comment: yeah of course that holds always for a fixed $n$ but not for all (big) $n$ uniformly.